# Two sets of the same data when clicking Submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I was wondering if someone would be able to answer this really (probably) simple question. I have a sign up script but when I click on "Submit", data is posted twice in to my SQL database. Below is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$sql = "";
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email_address, password, gender, city, country, verification_code, verified, sign_up_date) VALUES (
'$first_name',
'$last_name',
'$username',
'$email_address',
'$password',
'$gender',
'$city',
'$country',
'1234',
'Y',
'08/03/2017')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

echo "
<form action='signup.php' method='post'> 
<label id='first_name'> First name</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='first_name'><br/>

<label id='last_name'> Last name</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='last_name'><br/>

<label id='username'> Username</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='username'><br/>

<label id='email_address'>E-mail Address</label><br/>
<input type='email' name='email_address'><br/>

<label id='password'>Password</label><br/>
<input type='password' name='password'><br/>

<label id='gender'>Gender</label><br />
<select name='gender'>
<option value=''>Select...</option>
<option value='M'>Male</option>
<option value='F'>Female</option>
<option value='N'>Non-binary</option>
</select><br>

<label id='city'> City</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='city'><br/>

<label id='country'> Country</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='country'><br/>

<button type='submit' name='submit'>Sign up</button>

</form>

";
```

Comment: after insertion success redirect to your corresponding page

Comment: add hidden tag like `<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="Y">` and in your condition use `if(@$_POST['submitted']=='Y')`

Comment: have a look at POST/Redirect/GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @JYoThI that's fine I will try that. But why is the code submitting it twice? Is it simply because there's no redirect it will load the same page and resubmit the data again on loading because the fields are still populated? I am still trying to understand PHP logic and anything simple is stumping me :)